# Save stock data programmatically

Tags: magento2, php, stock, object-manager

You know how you've got;

```
$tempProduct->setData('price', 9.99);
$tempProduct->getResource()->saveAttribute($tempProduct,'price');
```

I want to do the same, except for stock;

```
$stockData = $tempProduct->getStockData();
$stockData['qty'] = 0;
$stockData['is_in_stock'] = 0;
$stockData['manage_stock'] = 1;
$stockData['use_config_manage_stock'] = 0;
$tempProduct->setStockData($stockData);
$tempProduct->getResource()->saveAttribute($tempProduct,'quantity_and_stock_status');
```

This doesn't work, it breaks at

```
$tempProduct->getResource()->saveAttribute($tempProduct,'quantity_and_stock_status');
```

Note: I do not want to use `$product-save()` / `$tempProduct->save()`

What can I do?

Comment: You want to update by API or?

Comment: API Object Manager / Object Model, ye

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this below code :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$sku = '24-MB01';
$stockValue = 5;
$productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$stockRegistry = $objectManager->create('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');
$product = $productRepository->get($sku); // Load Product by SKU
$stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId()); // Load Stock Item
$stockItem->setData('qty',$stockValue); //set updated quantity
$stockItem->setData('manage_stock',$stockData['manage_stock']);
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock',$stockData['is_in_stock']);
$stockItem->setData('use_config_notify_stock_qty',1);
$stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
```

**Note : Object Manager direct use is not good practise. You should follow construct method.**

Answer (score 0):

use this script it will help you out.

```
protected $stockRegistry;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
    ...
)
{
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
}
```

Now use  above instances and do update stock like this:

```
$sku = "YourSku";
$qty = 1;
$stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
$stockItem->setQty($qty);
$this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
```

Hope this will help